# Error with xml file in p5js ("syntaxerror : expected ; but found table")

Tags: javascript, xml, processing, p5.js

With p5.js I'm trying to draw 12 squares with random color that can be redraw when mouse is pressed - which I did with the code bellow :

```
function setup() {
//build-up canvas w/ 12 squares
createCanvas(800, 600);

for (var y=0; y<600;y+=200) {
  for (var x=0; x<800; x+=200) {
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    rect(x, y, 200, 200)
  }
}
function touchStarted() {
// figure-out where to redraw square
  var qX = (mouseX - (mouseX % 200)) / 200
  var qY = (mouseY - (mouseY % 200)) / 200

 fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
 rect(qX*200, qY*200, 200, 200);
}
```

But now i'm trying to save the data in a xml file with that kind of content :

```
<build>
    <square id="0" posx="0", posy="0">30</square>
    <square id="1" posx="200", posy="0">60</square>
```

And i'm trying to use it just as the reference tall to (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.XML) :

```
var xml;

function preload() {
  xml = loadXML("assets/data.xml");
}

function setup() {
  // build-up canvas w/ 12 squares
  createCanvas(800, 600);

  var children = xml.getChildren("build");

  for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var xpos = children[i].getNum("posx");
    var ypos = children[i].getNum("posy");
    var coul = children[i].getContent();
    fill(coul);
    rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 200);
  }
```

But I'm only get the error "SyntaxError: Expected ; but found table" so I'm really lost...

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
I'v changed the `var children = xml.getChildren("build");` to `var children = xml.getChildren("square");`

```
var xml;

function preload() {
  xml = loadXML("assets/data.xml");
}

function setup() {
  // build-up canvas w/ 12 squares
  createCanvas(800, 600);

  var children = xml.getChildren("square"); // <----- CHANGED IT FROM BUILD TO SQUARE

  for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var xpos = children[i].getNum("posx");
    var ypos = children[i].getNum("posy");
    var coul = children[i].getContent();
    fill(coul);
    rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 200);
  }
```

Also don't froget to close the  inside the xml file.
Should look like that:

```
<build>
<square id="0" posx="0", posy="0">30</square>
<square id="1" posx="200", posy="0">60</square>
</build>
```